# MySQL Select entire row from matching Group By value

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

Lets say I have 2 tables like so:

```
MyTable1:
Name    ID      Timestamp            TestNum    Grade
Alex    1101    2020-10-01 12:00:00  1          85
Alex    1101    2020-10-02 13:00:00  2          90
Alex    1101    2020-10-03  8:00:00  3          95
Alex    1101    2020-10-04 10:00:00  4          90

MyTable2:
ID      Avg  StDev
1101    90   4.08
```

I am trying to get the row of the first (Timestamp) instance where the grade was X standard deviations away.

```
ExpectedResults:
Name    ID      Timestamp            TestNum    StDevsAway
Alex    1101    2020-10-01 12:00:00  1          -1.23
Alex    1101    2020-10-02 13:00:00  2          0
Alex    1101    2020-10-03  8:00:00  3          1.23
```

The 4th row should not be returned as its Standard Deviations Away was already found at a previous Timestamp.

I'm still fairly new to MySQL, but this is where I'm at so far:

```
select a.Name
     , a.ID
     , a.Timestamp
     , a.TestNum
     , round( ( a.Grade - b.Avg ) / b.StDev, 2 ) as StDevsAway 
  from MyTable1 as a 
  join MyTable2 as b 
    on a.ID = b.ID 
 group 
    by round( ( a.Grade - b.Avg ) / b.StDev, 2 );
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Note that in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate. For further help, please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question is just about finding "first" row for each id/grade tupe. So (asssuming MySQL 8.0):

```
select t1.*
from (
    select t1.*, row_number() over(partition by id, grade order by timestamp) rn
    from mytable1 t1
) t1
where rn = 1
```

Then, you can bring the second table with a join if you like:

```
select t1.*, round(t1.grade - t2.avg) / t2.stdev, 2) stdevsaway
from (
    select t1.*, row_number() over(partition by id, grade order by timestamp) rn
    from mytable1 t1
) t1
inner join mytable2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
where rn = 1
```

In earlier versions, you can filter with a subquery:

```
select t1.*, round(t1.grade - t2.avg) / t2.stdev, 2) stdevsaway
from mytable1 t1
inner join mytable2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
where t1.timestamp = (
    select min(t11.timestamp) from mytable1 t11 where t11.id = t1.id and t11.grade = t1.grade
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Will this work with a mysql server 5.7 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: @CodyTroyer: no, this requires MySQL 8.0, as explained in the answer. I just added a solution for earlier versions.

Comment: Ah! oops, I missed that. The solution for earlier versions works like a charm! I will also look into potentially upgrading to MySQL 8.0 as it seems like there's a lot of cool tricks there. Thanks for your help GMB!

Answer (score 0):

In previous Versin and of Course in mysql8 as well you can do this.

this will exclude every testnum, that gas standard deviation,except the first one, for that user

**Schema (MySQL v5.5)**

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable1 (
  `Name` VARCHAR(4),
  `ID` INTEGER,
  `Timestamp` DATETIME,
  `TestNum` VARCHAR(7),
  `Grade` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO MyTable1
  (`Name`, `ID`, `Timestamp`, `TestNum`, `Grade`)
VALUES
  ('Alex', '1101', '2020-10-01 12:00:00', '1', '85'),
  ('Alex', '1101', '2020-10-02 13:00:00', '2', '90'),
  ('Alex', '1101', '2020-10-03 08:00:00', '3','95'),
  ('Alex', '1101', '2020-10-04 10:00:00', '4', '90');
  
  CREATE TABLE MyTable2 (
  `ID` INTEGER,
  `Avg` INTEGER,
  `StDev` FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO MyTable2
  (`ID`, `Avg`, `StDev`)
VALUES
  ('1101', '90', '4.08');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select 
    a.Name
    , a.ID
    , a.Timestamp
    , a.TestNum
    , round( ( a.Grade - b.Avg ) / b.StDev, 2 ) as StDevsAway 
from MyTable1 as a join MyTable2 as b on a.ID = b.ID 
WHERE 
TestNum NOT IN (SELECT TestNum
           FROM MyTable1 c
           WHERE c.`ID` = a.`ID` 
               AND c.`Grade` = b.Avg
           AND c.`TestNum`<> (SELECT MIN(TestNum)
                         FROM MyTable1 d
                          WHERE d.`ID` = a.`ID` 
                           AND d.`Grade` = b.Avg)
           );

| Name | ID   | Timestamp           | TestNum | StDevsAway |
| ---- | ---- | ------------------- | ------- | ---------- |
| Alex | 1101 | 2020-10-01 12:00:00 | 1       | -1.23      |
| Alex | 1101 | 2020-10-02 13:00:00 | 2       | 0          |
| Alex | 1101 | 2020-10-03 08:00:00 | 3       | 1.23       |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3woAVSw5hrav15jAmuWVdT/6)

Comment: Thank you nbk, your solution works as well, but the scalability of a triple subquery worries me a bit.

Comment: with asn index it is very fast